# invisible / hidden field in the constructor

Tags: haskell, types, derived-types, derived-instances

I am ploughing through [*Learn You a Haskell for Great Good*](http://learnyouahaskell.com/), and I have reached up to [section 8.4, "Derived Instances"](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses#derived-instances).  In this section, there's the following data type declaration:

```
data Person = Person { firstName :: String  
                     , lastName :: String  
                     , age :: Int  
                     } deriving (Eq)
```

While trying

```
*Main> mikeD == Person {firstName = "Michael", lastname = "Diamond", age = 43}
```

I got the following error:

```
<interactive>:55:41:
`lastname' is not a (visible) field of constructor `Person'
```

By correcting `lastname` to `lastName` I removed the error.

**Question:**

In the error message **the word `(visible)` hints to me that there must be the possibility of declaring a field as hidden / invisible**. Is this correct or not? If it is, how can I declare a field in the constructor as hidden, and what are the general scenarios where one would need to declare hidden fields?   If you could explain this by giving a simple example of their use, that would be appreciated.

Note: I could not find any reference to/details about hidden or invisible field in LYAH.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is possible to hide a field of a record, or a constructor of any data type, although not at the declaration site.  The idea is to simply choose not to export that constructor and/or field from the module, like so:

```
module MyModule (DT(C1, int, mStr)) where

data DT = C1 -- visible
             { 
               int :: Int, -- visible
               str :: String -- hidden
             }
        | C2 -- hidden
             {
               dbl :: Double, -- hidden
               mStr :: Maybe String -- visible
             }
```

Note that everything inside `MyModule` still has access to both constructors and all four fields, but in some other module that imports `MyModule` only the exported ones are visible.

Comment: "It is not possible to export some fields of a given constructor and not other fields of the same constructor, however." Yes, it is. `module MyModule (DT(C1, int))` only exports `int`, but not `str`. Also note that your `DT(C1)` does not export any of the fields, so `int` and `str` are invisible in your code sample.

Comment: @sepp2k I did not know that!  I will correct my answer, thank you.

Comment: "only visible as a function, not as a field" — not true either. You can use it to update the record.

Comment: No, it's not corrected. The way you export it doesn't matter. What you're trying to achieve ("only visible as a function, not as a field") is simply not possible. For that, you have to define it as a function, not as a field.